# Thickbox - secure connection

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, thickbox

Hi Stack overflow members,

I am wanting to usethickbox as a secure enquiry form on my website... All is set up OK, but as the thick box (secure page) loads on top of the non secure page, is there anyway you can change the url to show https and also ensure the padlock appears at the bottom of the page?

Wasn't sure if this is possible, if not I may have to force the secure enquiry form to open as a new window but to set width and height diomensions.

As always, your help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. I'd force a refresh of the page and send the user back to the base page over https and then fire the thickbox overlay.